# How do I determine if a number in a list exists in a range?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looping through a range but every time the `i` in range is equal to one of the integers in `check_list`, I should `continue` and iterate next. Here's my code:

```
check_list = [23,5,6,3,6,3]
for i in range(1000):
    if i == one of the numbers in check_list:
        continue
    # do something here
```

Comment: Do you mean you want `if i in check_list:`?

Comment: Simply delete `== one of the numbers` from your code.

Answer (score 3):

Use operator `in`:

```
check_list = [23,5,6,3,6,3]
for i in range(1000):
    if i in check_list:
        continue
    # do something here
```

Answer (score 2):

You need just to use:

```
if i in check_list:
```

Take a look at this example:

```
>>> check_list = [23, 5, 6, 3, 6, 3]
>>> for i in range(10):
...     if i in check_list:
...         print(i)
...
3
5
6
```